# strsplit by integers in R

Tags: r, string

Suppose I have strings such like:

```
   "0cGy-GCSF6hr-f-m5"
   "100cGy-LPS12hr-m-m2"
   "300cGy-NOTRT24hr-f-m2"
   "0cGy-6h-m1"
```

It's sort of complicated, but what I want is to retrieve from them to:

```
"GCSF", "LSP", "NOTRT", "NOTRT"
```

which means if there are none of "GCSF", "LSP", "NOTRT", then return "NOTRT".
And integers before h/hr

```
6, 12, 24, 6
```

I have tried a while but is very frustrated. Somebody have good ideas?

Comment: Did you mean to have that second "NOTRT" in the expected output? If so, where is it coming from?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. See the updated.

Comment: `do.call('rbind', strsplit(gsub('.*\\-([A-Z]*)(\\d+)h.*', '\\1 \\2', s), ' '))` and fill in the '' with notrt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

s <- c("0cGy-GCSF6hr-f-m5", "100cGy-LPS12hr-m-m2",
    "300cGy-NOTRT24hr-f-m2", "0cGy-6h-m1")

stri_extract_all_regex(s, "[A-Z]+(?=[0-9]+hr?-)") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    ifelse(is.na(.), "NOTRT", .)

stri_extract_all_regex(s, "[0-9]+(?=hr?-)") %>% unlist()
```

Comment: A quick question, what if there is no "h" or "hr" such like "0cGy-LPS6-m1"and I wanted to have the number 6? Thanks

Comment: @DavidZ Use `ifelse`.

Comment: If number of character in the preceding string has an upper bound (let's say 12) you can combine lookahead and lookbehind: `stri_extract_all_regex(s, "(?<=-[A-Z]{0,12})[0-9]+(?=(hr|h)?-)")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using 'dplyr' and 'stringr' that returns vectors instead of lists and puts "NOTRT" in empty slots for the character clusters and 6 in the empty slots for the numbers:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

letters <- s %>%
  str_extract_all("[A-Z]+(?=[0-9]+hr?)")  %>%
  lapply(., function(x) {if (length(x)==0) {"NOTRT"} else {x} })  %>%
  unlist(.)

numbers <- s %>%
  str_extract_all("[0-9]+(?=hr?)") %>%
  lapply(., function(x) {if (length(x)==0) {"6"} else {x} })  %>%
  as.numeric(unlist(.))
```

Using your data with the example from the comments on the previous answer appended...

```
    s <- c("0cGy-GCSF6hr-f-m5", "100cGy-LPS12hr-m-m2", "300cGy-NOTRT24hr-f-m2", "0cGy-6h-m1", "0cGy-LPS6-m1")
```

...here is the output that produces:

```
> letters
[1] "GCSF"  "LPS"   "NOTRT" "NOTRT" "NOTRT"

> numbers
[1]  6 12 24  6  6
```